# vb.net cannot insert more than 2 columns to .mdb file

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

For some reason when I try to add a 3rd columns in my insert command I get the "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." error. However when I only have 2 values to insert into 2 columns it works just fine.  I'm a bit confused as to why that may be. (tip: I may not be using the correct connect string, the file type is an Access 2000 Database)

```
    Dim Cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim objCmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim Con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\Files\keysDB.mdb")
    SQL = "INSERT INTO KeyBuffer(keypad, SID, Time) VALUES('1', '1337', '" & DateTime.Now.ToString & "')"
    Cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)
    Con.Open()
    objCmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)
    objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Con.Close()
```

Comment: Are you saying if you put this in a for 1 to 3 loop it will die on the third iteration?  Also, are all three columns in the KeyBuffer table text fields?  BTW, always use parameters.

Comment: In it's current form the code fails on the insert command.  However if I were to use:

    `SQL = "INSERT INTO KeyBuffer(keypad, SID) VALUES('1', '1337')"`

It would work just fine.  And the 'Time' field is a date field not text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field name you are using for Time is likely a keyword.  Try placing brackets around it:

```
"INSERT INTO KeyBuffer(keypad, SID, [Time])...
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized shortly before this that it was an issue with my 'Time' insert.  That's what I was missing.

Comment: @BrentHacker The question was a bit confusing because fields are generally referred to as columns, not rows.  Glad to help.